# $o(g^{k})=\frac{o(g)}{\gcd(o(g),k)}$ order of a power of a group element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let's say $g \in G$, where $G$ is a group. Also $\operatorname{ord}(g)=n$. Then we have to prove that:

a) $\operatorname{ord}(g^k)=l $, where $l$ is the least number bigger than (or equal to)  $1$, such that $n\mid kl$.

b) $\operatorname{ord}(g^k)=n \Leftrightarrow \gcd(k,n)=1$.

With a) I tried to go like:

$(g^k)^l=g^{k*l}=g^k=g^n*g^k=g^{n+k}$ and then from second and last equality: $kl=n+k$ from what I have that $k(l-1)=n$, and I am stuck. It may be simple or maybe I've gone a wrong path.

With b) I have no idea how to start, but it seems like a conclusion from a).

I would appreciate any help or hint. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $\operatorname{ord}(g^k)$ is the least $l\geq 1$ such that $(g^k)^l=1$; but since $\operatorname{ord}(g)=n$, $1=(g^k)^l=g^{kl}$ if and only if $n\mid kl$. This proves a).

As you said, b) is simply a consequence of a): indeed a) tells us that $k\operatorname{ord}(g^k)$ is the least multiple of $k$ that is also a multiple of $n$, and thus the least common multiple of $k$ and $n$; thus
$$\operatorname{ord}(g^k)=\frac{\mathrm{lcm}(n,k)}{k}=\frac{nk}{\gcd(n,k)k}=\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)},$$
and thus $\operatorname{ord}(g^k)=n\Leftrightarrow \gcd(n,k)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ g^{\large kx}=1 \!\iff\! n\mid kx\!\iff\! n\mid kx,nx\!\iff\! n\mid (kx,nx)\!=\! (k,n)x\!\iff\! n/(k,n)\mid x\ $

Since $\,\ell = {\rm ord}\,g^{\large k}\,$ is the *least* such $\,x>0,\,$ clearly  $\ \ell = n/(k,n),\ $ so  $\ \ell = n\iff (k,n)= 1.\,$